# Redirect stdinput of netcat to current stdout of bash script

Tags: bash, io-redirection

i have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 4>&1
nc localhost 100 0<&4 &
echo hello 
echo ....
```

I just want to send hello and other things to netcat but that approach doesn't work.
I know `echo "hello" | nc localhost` works but i don't need it, same for `"nc localhost 0<file.txt echo "hello" >file.txt`.
Named pipe also work, but i'd want to know if something easy like above can be achieved.

Comment: This can't work. A file-descriptor is not bidirectional -- reading from it doesn't read what's written to it.

Comment: You have both `bash` and `sh` tags -- they're not the same, pick one.

Comment: Have you tried `{ echo hello; echo ...; } |  nc localhost 100` ?

Comment: under [tag:bash], you could `exec {tcpsock}<>/dev/tcp/localhost/100; echo >&$tcpsock hello; read -u $tcpsock -r answer;echo $answer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try Bash's coprocesses:

```bash
coproc nc ( netcat localhost 100 )
```

The above command starts `netcat` in the background and links its standard input to file descriptor `${nc[1]}` and its standard output to `${nc[0]}`.

You can then manipulate those file descriptors in order to replace your current stdin and stdout:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
coproc nc ( netcat localhost 100 )

# Current stdin and stdout are saved in old_stdin and old_stdout,
# then they are replaced with the input and output of the coprocess
exec {old_stdin}<&0 {old_stdout}>&1 <&${nc[0]} >&${nc[1]}

echo "This is sent to netcat"
read reply

# We restore the former stdin and stdout
exec <&$old_stdin >&$old_stdout
echo "This was received from netcat: $reply"
```